# segueをプログラム遷移する際のデータ移行

Tags: swift, xcode6

swiftでsegueの遷移時の処理で分からないので分かる方教えて下さい。

segueをIBを使うのではなくidentifierを設定してプログラムで使います。
2つの画面ViewControllerとPuzzleViewControllerがありperformSegueWithIdentifierを使って遷移させます。遷移方法は画像を作成してそちらからonClickButtonのアクションで移動します。TouchUpInsideする画像によって次の画面でのアクションが異なるため画像を設置した際にtag(cTag)を設定します。そこで質問ですがprepareFoSegueメソッド内にsender?.tagを設定したのですがなぜかnilが返ってきます。onClickButtonメソッド内でsender?.tagを設定するとちゃんとしたタグの数値が返ってくるのですがprepareFoSegueメソッドが発生した時点で参照範囲外になってしまうからでしょうか？またどういった考え方をすればいいでしょうか？

```
func cImageMake(cImageName:String,cTag:Int,cWideth:CGFloat,cHeight:CGFloat,cText:String){
    //アイコン画像の生成
    let cImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: cImageName) as UIImage!
    let cImageButton = UIButton()
    cImageButton.tag = cTag
    cImageButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75)
    cImageButton.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/4 * cWideth , y: self.view.frame.height/4 * cHeight)
    cImageButton.setImage(cImage, forState: .Normal)
    cImageButton.addTarget(self, action: "onClickCButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(cImageButton)
    //アイコン文字の生成
    var cTextField:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75))
    cTextField.text = cText
    cTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    cTextField.enabled = false
    cTextField.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/4 * cWideth, y: self.view.frame.height/4 * cHeight )
    self.view.addSubview(cTextField)
}

//ボタンイベントPuzzleViewControllerを表示
func onClickCButton(sender: AnyObject){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goPuzzleSegue", sender: sender.tag)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goPuzzleSegue"{
        let puzzleViewController:PuzzleViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PuzzleViewController
        puzzleViewController.castleId = sender?.tag
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//ボタンイベントPuzzleViewControllerを表示
// func onClickCButton(sender: AnyObject){
func onClickCButton(sender: UIButton) { // senderの型をUIButtonに「決めつけ」る。
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goPuzzleSegue", sender: sender) // sender.tag → sender
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goPuzzleSegue"{
        // Optional Bindingを採用。
        if let theButton = sender as? UIButton {
            let puzzleViewController:PuzzleViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PuzzleViewController
            puzzleViewController.castleId = theButton.tag
        }
```

メソッドの引数で、`sender`の型を`AnyObject`としていることに注目してください。`AnyObject`に`tag`というプロパティはありませんので、`sender.tag`は意味をなしません。
`tag`というプロパティを持っているのは、`UIView`とそのサブクラス（`UIButton`も含まれる）なので、`sender`を`UIView`ないし`UIButton`にダウンキャストする必要があります。
`func onClickCButton(sender: UIButton)`は、直接引数の型を変更しています。
`if let theButton = sender as? UIButton`は、Optional Bindingを使ってダウンキャストしています。ダウンキャストに失敗すると、`theButton`には、`nil`が入ります。

※メソッド・関数の引数に限らず、`Any`や`AnyObject`という型が出てきたら、なんらかのダウンキャストが必要なんだろうなと、予測しておくといいでしょう。たとえば、配列`Array`や辞書`Dictionary`の要素を、`AnyObject`型としておくことはよくあります。要素を取り出したときに、ダウンキャストしないと、そのままでは使えないことがよくあります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。わたりやすい解説でした。tagのサブクラスについて理解してなかったので大変勉強になりました。試してみましたがうまくいきました。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: 『AnyObjectにtagというプロパティはありませんので、sender.tagは意味をなしません。
tagというプロパティを持っているのは、UIViewとそのサブクラス（UIButtonも含まれる）なので、senderをUIViewないしUIButtonにダウンキャストする必要があります。』：

『You can also call any Objective-C method and access any property without casting to a more specific class type. This includes Objective-C compatible methods marked with the @objc attribute.
』（https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html）
とあるので、これは違うと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: @ppm おっしゃっていることがよくわかりません。ダウンキャストは不用ということですか？Objective-Cで書いても、ここはダウンキャストするところだと思うのですが？

Comment: @Harawo はい、私も `sender as? UIButton` の部分は同じように書くと思います。

ただ、私が特に気になったのは、『`sender.tag`は意味をなしません。』とおっしゃられていることと、実際、回答で `onClickButton` の中の `sender.tag` を `sender` に書き換えられているところです。

元のコードのままでも質問者様の意図通りに動作すると思いますし、根本的な問題の解決には関係ないと思うのですが、なぜ書き換えられたのでしょうか。

もっと言えば、質問中のコードのどこに根本的な問題があり、それをどうのように解決したらいいのかが書かれていない気がするのですが、いかがでしょうか？